# Can world without earth begin an artwork's strife?

Tags: aesthetics, heidegger

In art there is:

> [an](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/heidegger-aesthetics/) “essential strife” between two interconnected dimensions of
>   intelligibility (revealing and concealing) which Heidegger calls
>   “world” and “earth” in his most famous work on art.

I claimed, in a very short essay for school, that a particular poet was second rate because their technique begins with *unconcealment*.

Can world without earth begin an artwork's strife?

Comment: fwiw the poet was ted hughes and i FLUNKED

Comment: i edited out some reasoning about the importance it does not. apologies for not (ever) being clear